# What does ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE mean in the Ghost-CLI 'ghost start' failure report?

Tags: mysql, ssl, ubuntu-20.04, ghost-blog, virtualmin

I am installing the Ghost platform onto Ubuntu 20.4. However, there is an authentication mode error that is blocking the start of the application.

Does anyone know what this is asking to be fixed? This system qualifies with the technical prerequisites. I am also using Virtualmin to manage databases for the most part.

[Ghost-CLI - ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxdKi.png)

Sounds like an SSLconnection issue. Anyone else encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running these commands.

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
```

You had to change the 'plugin' field as well because may it was set to 'auth_socket'.

After that, you can connect as `mysql -u root` without a password.

#### If the above solution doesn't work:

Check the file `config.production.json` and see if the password filed matches the MySQL password or not. If there is no password field in

```json
mysql{
...
}
```

then add a password filed and insert your password.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The DB I was trying to use wasn't compatible.